# Why am I getting the error 'A<int>' is not an accessible base of 'S<int>' for a base class's base class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to call the class function `A<F>::f()` from within class `S`, but I'm getting the following errors when I instantiate an `S` object ( `S<int>s` ) and call it's `f` member function ( `s.f()` ) :

> source.cpp: In instantiation of '`int S<F>::f() [with F = int]`':
>   source.cpp:30:21: required from here
>   source.cpp:22:25: error: '`A<int>`' is not an accessible base of '`S<int>`'

Note that this works when I replace `return A<F>::f();` inside the declaration of class `S` with `return C<A, F>::f();`. But I'm wondering why I can't do it the other way...

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class A {
   public:
      int f();
};

template <typename T> int A<T>::f() {
   return sizeof(T);
}

template <template <typename> class E, typename D> class C : E<D> {
   public:
      int f() {
         return E<D>::f();
      }
};

template <typename F> class S : C<A, F> {
   public:
      int f() {
         return A<F>::f();
      }
};

int main() {

   S<int>s;

   std::cout << s.f();

}
```

Any help is appreciated and if you require further clarification please feel free to comment.

**Update**

Since this questions is resolved I guess I should post the code that actually worked:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class A {
   public:
      int f();
};

template <typename T> int A<T>::f() {
   return sizeof(T);
}

template <template <typename> class E, typename D> class C : public E<D> {
   public:
      int f() {
         return E<D>::f();
      }
};

class S : public C<A, int> {};

int main() {

   S s;

   std::cout << s.f(); // 4

}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
template <typename F> class S : C<A, F> 
                               ^
```

You don't specify a `public` inheritance, so it defaults to `private`, making the base classes inaccessible.

Comment: Nevermind that last comment. It's working now that I replaced *all* the classes with public inheritance.

Comment: Another idea would be to make them all structs so we can have default public inheritance. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think it is just a matter of using `public` class inheritance. Try with:

```
template <template<class> class E, typename D> class C : public E<D> {
   public:
      int f() {
         return E<D>::f();
      }
};

template <typename F> class S : public C<A, F> {
   public:
      int f() {
         return A<F>::f();
      }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to call `A`'s version of `f()` you use the notation `A<F>::f()`. If `A<F>` had a `static` member function `f()` this function would, indeed, be called. However, `A<F>` only has a non-`static` member function `f()`, i.e., the call gets implicitly translated to `this->A<F>::f()`. However, `S<F>` doesn't have a `A<F>` as an accessible base (it is a `private` base of `C<A, F>`). From the looks of it you want to delegate to `C<A, F>`s version of `f()`:

```
C<A, F>::f();
```

which should work because `C<A, F>` is an accesible base of `S<int>` or make the `E<D>` base of `C` accessible by making it either `public` or `protected`.

Comment: Not sure this is true. In this case `A<F>` is a private base of the type. Lookup will find the injected type name before it gets to check the namespace level, so whether the member method in `A` is static or not does not really matter.